# RMSLE interpretation on Kaggle

Tags: r, machine-learning

Found something wrong with [RMSLE description](https://www.kaggle.com/c/yelp-recruiting/details/evaluation)

It says:

> An absolute error of 1 vote is much **more** significant to a review
>   with 3 total votes than it is to a review with 100 total votes.

I think the Loss function doesn't penalise vote=100 too much compares to vote=3, when you do a plot of 
log(1+x) in google, natural log function will smooth all the values even it's large. Y-axis is a smooth transformation from various different x value.

[image: Plot of log(1+x)]

Also, ( log(1+1) - log(1+3) )^2 = 0.0906 < ( log(1+1) - log(1+100) )^2 = 2.901

So,
In my observation the bold text: 'more' should be changed to 'less', is that right ?

Comment: @Pascal, Let's see how R user + Statistician answer this. :) Move to SE for achieve later on.

Comment: I think that the statement is correct. An absolute error of one vote for a review with 3 votes corresponds to a relative error of about 33%, while an absolute error of one vote represents a relative error of only 1% in the case of 100 reviews.

Comment: @Pascal, After a few clicks. I found many 'Kaggle' question has not been asked (>2yrs) in here. 'Cross-Validation' section is more related to this topic. So, Let's me to there. Thanks.

Comment: @RHertel  What you said is 'relative error' 1/3 > 1/100 though. So,  log(1+1) - log(3+1) = -0.7 >  log(1+1) - log(100+1)  = -1.7 might be called 'absolute error', however, when they are squared (^2), former one is less then later one.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the relative error, which I think is decisive. The absolute error is one vote in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you measuring the "absolute error" of a vote in the wrong way. I would say that an absolute error of a single vote would mean that the absolute difference between the predicted and actual amount of votes is 1.

This would yield in the case of 3 total (and actual) votes

(log(1+2) - log(1+3))^2 = 0,0156096879

(log(1+4) - log(1+3))^2 = 0,00939155062

versus in the case of a 100 total (and actual) votes

(log(1+99) - log(1+100))^2 = 0,00001867427325

(log(1+101) - log(1+100))^2 = 0,00001830811232

From which you can see that an absolute error of a single vote is punished more in the case of 3 total votes, and will become more significant in the RMSLE when the actual number of votes equals 3.

Which does reflect the statement made.